Can not set height of child elements to height of parent container with dynamic height
In the following code, I don't understand how I can set the height of each of the children elements (the ones where the className is ???) to the same height as the container with the ref. I have seen people implement workarounds with absolute positioning, however, I cannot get this to work here because there is more than one child element. Does anyone know how to solve this using css only, or is it strictly necessary to use javascript in this case?
<div className="h-[632px] flex flex-col">
  <div className="h-32">
    {/* Some content */}
  </div>
  <div
    className="relative flex flex-1 justify-between space-x-10 overflow-y-auto"
    ref={ref}
  >
    <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
      <div className="???" />
      <div className="???" />
      <div className="???" />
    </div>
    <div className="sticky top-0 flex h-full w-96 items-center justify-center">
      {/* Some content */}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Edit: I might also have to make the height of the container with h-32 dynamic, hence I do not want to use a solution with calculate
Edit: The code is available on https://play.tailwindcss.com/Tt3Hr9AqNH now. Each of the boxes (with title and content) should have a height equal to the distance between the bottom of the red box and the green border.

Can you set up a proper live example using something like https://play.tailwindcss.com or similar for us, please?

@Lenny - your  question is not clear to me, if I understand correctly here is solution for this:  https://play.tailwindcss.com/2Yn83MGrP4

@MinalChauhan This is exactly what I wanted. Apparently the problem were the flex and flex-col classes. I didn't know that applying flex changes the way relative sizes are applied. Thanks!



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Equal Height Child Elements with CSS Grid</title>
<style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between child elements as you want */
  }

  .child-element {
    /* Add styles for child elements */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-element">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child-element">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child-element">Child 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
